# Find a hash encryption input from an output

Tags: python, algorithm, encryption, hash

I have this function `hash()` that encrypts a given string to an integer.

```
letters = 'weiojpknasdjhsuert'

def hash(string_input):
  h = 3

  for i in range(0, len(string_input)):
    h = h * 43 + letters.index(string_input[i])

  return h
```

So if I do `print(hash('post'))`, my output is: `11231443`

How can I find what my input needs to be to get an output like `1509979332193868` if the input can only be a string from `letters`? There is a formula inside the loop body but I couldn't figure out how to reverse it.

Comment: Just to make straight the terminology used, please look at [Fundamental difference between Hashing and Encryption algorithms](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4948322/4046632)

Comment: I don't think the formula is reversible, it may even be the case that multiple strings hash to the same value.

Comment: So how can I find out what the input can be given a single output?

Comment: @Barnar What if its a string made up exclusively from characters in a series of characters?

Comment: What is `letters` specifically?

Comment: @Mark Fixed it. Letters is actually `chars`

Comment: I wonder what you expect to happen if *string_input* contains any characters that are **not** in *letters*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seem like since 43 is larger than your alphabet, you can just reverse the math. I don't know how to *prove* there are no hash collisions, so this may have edge cases. For example:

```
letters = 'weiojpknasdjhsuert'

def hash(string_input):
    h = 3

    for i in range(0, len(string_input)):
        h = h * 43 + letters.index(string_input[i])

    return h

n = hash('wepostjapansand')
print(n)
# 9533132150649729383107184

def rev(n):
    s = ''
    while n:
        l = n % 43  # going in reverse this is the index of the next letter
        n -= l      # now reverse the math...subtract that index
        n //= 43    # and divide by 43 to get the next n
        if n:
            s = letters[l] + s
    return s

print(rev(n))
# wepostjapansand
```

With a more reasonable alphabet, like lowercase ascii and a space, this still seem to be okay:

```
from string import ascii_lowercase 

letters = ascii_lowercase + ' '

def hash(string_input):
    h = 3

    for i in range(0, len(string_input)):
        h = h * 43 + letters.index(string_input[i])

    return h

n = hash('this is some really long text to test how well this works')
print(n)
# 4415562436659212948343839746913950248717359454765313646276852138403823934037244869651587521298

def rev(n):
    s = ''
    # with more compact logic
    while n > 3:
        s = letters[n % 43] + s
        n = (n - (n % 43)) // 43
    return s

print(rev(n))
# this is some really long text to test how well this works
```

The basic idea is that after all the math, the last number is:

```
prev * 43 + letter_index
```

This means you can recover the final letter index by taking the `prev` modulus 43. Then subtract that and divide by 43 (which is just the reverse of the math) and do it again until your number is zero.

Comment: I didn't notice that `alphabet` was so small, I assumed it would include all uppercase and lowercase letters, so at least 52 characters, which is larger than 43.

Comment: Your first `def rev(n)` actually works. Would you mind explaining your logic?

Comment: Yeah, @Barmar, I think that's right. With all the upper and lower case letters, this seems to work with a bigger multiple like 59

Comment: @oo92, I added some explanation at the end...hope that's helpful.

Comment: I'm curious: Why doesn't the initial value `h = 3` appear in the reverse?

Comment: @Barmar it gets eaten by the last integer division since 3 is smaller than 43 (which is also why that `if n` test is there otherwise it would print an extra letter). I suppose `while n > 3:` would also be an option that avoids this.